# Pass JSON variables from REACT JS to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, json, react-router, upload, react-typescript

I would like to pass JSON variable from REACT JS to typescript with click of button:

There are 2 pages:

1. Page 1: userDetails.js (This page redirect after filling a form to the next page "upload")
   Submit option

   ```
   let history = useHistory();
   const submitForm = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   try {
   let jsonObj = [];
   let item = {}
   item['project'] = event.target.proj.value
   item['corporateId'] = event.target.cid.value
   item['backOffice'] = event.target.bo.value
   item['environment'] = event.target.env.value

   jsonObj.push(item);

   console.log(jsonObj);
   alert('Your Details are validated!');
   history.push({
     pathname: './upload',
        state: jsonObj 
   });
   setValues({
     proj: '', cid: '', bo: '', env: ''
   });
   } catch (event) {
   alert(`Validation failed! ${event.message}`);
   }

   }
   ```
2. Page 2: Upload page where I would like to read the JSON file but this page is in typescript (fileUploader.tsx)

   ```
    const FileUploader = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { state } = this.props.location
    }
   ```

Error: this object is possibly undefined.

How can i pass this JSON variable from react JS to react Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

If you review your code, you have defined function component and trying to get the props which is incorrect, please use like this:

```
type FileUploaderProps = {
    // define all the props here 
    location: any
}
const FileUploader = (props: FileUploaderProps ): JSX.Element => {
 const { state } = props.location
}
```

And to get the location params you can make use of `useLocation()`.

Comment: Thank you @Ajay for your quick response. Sorry but I am quite new to it. When i am using as as follows, it still doesn't give me JSON params: Page 1: type FileUploaderProps = {
          name: jsonObj;
          location: any;
        }       Page 2:  const FileUploader = (props: FileUploaderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { state } = props.location
  console.log('MetaData Item: ' + location)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it. The real issue was with the array object. So there are 2 solutions for Page 2 as follows:

Note: `history.push` is only meant to pass string instead of object and therefore, use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
JSON.stringify(jsonObj) // Page 1: This will convert your array object to string
JSON.parse(location.state.data) // Page 2: This will reconvert your string to JSON object
```

Page 1: JavaScript

```
let jsonToString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
history.push("/upload", {data: jsonToString, from: "userForm"})
```

Page 2:

1. Convert the typescript to javascript and then you can call the location.

   ```
   const location = useLocation();
   const userData = JSON.parse(location.state.data)
   ```
2. In typescript, you can read location as follows:

   ```
    interface customState {data: string}
    let customLocationState = location.state as customState
    const userData = JSON.parse(customLocationState.data)
   ```